# Il s'en faut de peu

Tags: grammaire

Bonjour !

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre la structure de cette phrase.

Il s'en faut de peu que nous nous rencontrions à Londres la semaine dernière.

La seconde partie de la phrase fait clairement référence au passé. Dans ce cas-ci, ne faudrait-il pas qu'au moins un des prédicats soit exprimé au passé ?
Ma suggestion : Il s'en est fallu de peu que nous nous rencontrions à Londres la semaine dernière.

Merci d'avance

Comment: Où as-tu rencontré la phrase que tu cites ? Peux-tu donner le contexte ? Telle que tu la transcris elle n'est effectivement pas logique. Il y a une erreur soit sur *il s'en faut de peu*, soit sur *la semaine dernière*. Le verbe *falloir* est impersonnel (n'existe pas à toutes les personnes) mais par contre il faut adapter [le temps](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/conjugaison/falloir) selon le contexte. Donc ta suggestion est correcte.

Comment: Je ne dirais pas nécessairement qu'il y a une _erreur_. Ça se comprend, avec un effet de style pour le temps présent de la principale, peut-être pour rendre une narration plus vivante. Et c'est un peu bizarre parce que le _rencontrions_ est presque rare. Ta suggestion est très correcte, voire "_hyper-correcte_", cad, on n'utiliserait pas à l'oral de nos jours. Même à l'écrit, c'est un peu guindé à mon avis. En fait, le présent dans la principale pourrait aussi être une façon de relâcher ta suggesion.

Comment: @Frank les cas où on peut ne pas respecter la concordance des temps sont quand même très rares. Une énumération de faits passés mis au présent pour mieux souligner un impact ici et maintenant, peut-être. Pour la forme correcte, on la rencontre très fréquemment dans la production écrite. Cela ne me parait pas être une raison suffisante pour qualifier une écriture de "guindée".

Answer (score 1):

Votre suggestion " Il s'en est fallu de peu que nous nous rencontrions à Londres la semaine dernière." est cohérente et me convient. La tournure "Il s'en faut de peu que nous nous rencontrions à Londres la semaine dernière." ne choquerait cependant pas à l'oral même si on dirait plutôt " Il s'en est fallu de peu que nous nous soyons rencontrés à Londres la semaine dernière." La tournure la plus compréhensible serait "Encore un peu et nous nous serions rencontrés à Londres la semaine dernière."

Comment: *Encore un peu et on se serait rencontrés à Londres, la semaine dernière.*